# jQuery .html and .append in variable

Tags: jquery, append

I want to create a variable with the append and HTML function. The reason is when a person clicks on a div he should be replace the element, otherwise he should add the element instead of replace it.

As example, my variable calls: `var clicked = true;`

My jQuery code looks like this:

```
// if a user clicks, replace the image
if(clicked == true){
   var type = '.html';
// else (when the page is loading), add the image
}else{
   var type = '.append';
}

// use the var type
container.find('.img') + type + (data.img);
```

If the image exists he should not add an new one, but he needs te replace him. If he exists he should replace the current image with the new one.

I know, I could do something like this:

```
if(clicked == true){
   container.find('.img').html(data.img);
}else{
   container.find('.img').append(data.img);
}
```

But I have a lot of elements, and I think this is a more effective way to write the code.

But is this possible?

Comment: use each loop if multiple element in container

Comment: Yes, I think that @SureshSuthar is right, but to answer to your question we need to see a bit more of your html code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get the function name as a string, You could try to use `Bracket Notation` to call that function.

```
var type = 'html';
container.find('.img')[type](data.img); //same with container.find('.img').html(data.img);
```

you could refer more in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)